# placeholder using php or xhtml attribute on search

Tags: php, forms, search

I know that when you want to have a value in the form like search you can do like

```
<input type='text' name='search' value='$_GET[search]' placeholder='  Search'/>
```

by using `placeholder="value"` you will have the text in the form when click it will be disappear, but that is only valid in HTML5. Even though most of the browsers now are support (maybe few still not), but this is an assignment, so I'm not suppose to use HTML5 or JavaScript. Where JavaScript you can also do something like.

```
<input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter your text here...') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter your text here...';" value="Enter your text here..." />
```

So now I only have two option left.

1. is to find any attribute that is actually valid in XHTML 1.0
2. Use php to have the value like `placeholder`

Comment: Use javascript is ok, what's the problem?

Comment: @xdazz Assignment is not allow to use that.

Comment: Not allowing you to use modern web technologies is tying your hands behind your back. You could put in using PHP the text, but you'd have to replace the text when they enter the field which can not be done using no scripting language.

Comment: @Hammerstein that is too bad :(..... it just that I want to have the same like what in `stackoverflow` search had like `placeholder` you know what I mean right?

Comment: @Ali Without javascript or html5 placeholder, it is not possible.

Comment: I appreciate that, but if you're being restricted in your use of technology then you don't really have a choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop stop stop. What you want? Placeholders is a CLIENT-SIDE technique. You cannot create placeholders with server-side technology.  You can check the values on the server side anyway for security goals.

Comment: This is just an assignment where we do not have to care about security, and the purpose it just to have something like `placeholder` in an old version or using php something like that.

Comment: OP can't use HTML5 or JS, placeholder is a HTML5 attribute. He could put initial text in using a server side language, but couldn't replace the value.